# Lemon tree advice for new Gardener

Tags: trees, lemons

First time posting.  I grew a lemon tree 7 years ago from a small seed.  After outgrowing the pot (it’s about 6 feet tall) I decided to plant it in the ground (North Carolina). It has really taken off! It grew several more leaves and another foot.  But now we’ve had an unusually chilly Fall.  I’m worried this may have been a bad idea and concerned it won’t survive through Winter.  I mulched several inches around the base, fertilized, and it gets plenty of sun.  Any advice?